# Can we use sencha touch to develop web application?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, extjs4.1

I am familiar to both Sencha Touch and ExtJs. My next project is web application. I am planning to use Sencha Touch to develop web application, *because in sencha touch contains lot of graph components and also touch components events available.* **Can I use sencha Touch to develop web application?**. Please anybody can suggest me. Great appreciate.

Answer (score 2):

The selection of ExtJS or Touch framework is not about web or non-web applications, but about the device you want to run the result on. For desktop, use Ext JS, for mobiles use Sencha Touch.

Both have rich charting.

Comment: Ok Thank you, got it. In feature laptops/Desktops will be recognize touch events. so planning to use Sencha Touch. but extjs components doesn't have touch recognize. What you say?

Comment: Probably the reverse is better as Ext 5 beta supports touch events. However, it depends on what you really need.

Answer (score 1):

By web application if you mean HTML client side code your answer will be yes you can.

Sencha touch is by nature HTML based.

For native applications you used builder tools to obtain native ports.

In other words, yes you can develop web applications.

Answer (score 0):

Also (as usual) check out the documentation for both [ExtJS](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/getting_started/welcome_to_extjs.html) and [SenchaTouch](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.2/#!/guide) as they will both describe how to deploy as a web application.

Answer (score 0):

Just a heads up, i've developed on both and Touch Interfaces wouldn't look very good on a web browser, they are designed and optimized for html 5 enabled mobile devices like tablets.

ExtJS however is developed for a desktop web experience, and the components look a lot better on a computer when rendered in an html 5 web page.